# How to create User and Role for Admin in .NET 7?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identity, .net-7.0

When the database is created, it is empty and I need to have a model for the user in the **AspNetUsers** table and a role for example admin in **AspNetRoles** and also in the **AspNetUserRoles** model these two should be connected to work properly.
How to create this item to create them when there is no data in the database.

I have created the user and role model as follows:

User

```
public class AdminConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        var admin = new User
        {
            Id = "1",
            UserName = "masteradmin",
            NormalizedUserName = "MASTERADMIN",

            Email = "Admin@Admin.com",
            NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@ADMIN.COM",
            PhoneNumber = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
            SecurityStamp = new Guid().ToString(),
            Password = "Password"
        };
        admin.PasswordHash = PassGenerate(admin);
        builder.HasData(admin);
    }
    public string PassGenerate(User user)
    {
        var passHash = new PasswordHasher<User>();
        return passHash.HashPassword(user, "password");
    }
}
```

Role

```
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityRole> builder)
    {
        var role = new IdentityRole
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Admin",
            ConcurrencyStamp = "b35494cf-4040-47e3-a6de-dee4b6f8e250",
            NormalizedName = "ADMIN",
        };
        builder.HasData(role);
    }
}
```

and add in DbContext as follows:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        ...
        // some codes for the relationship between tables
        ...

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AdminConfiguration());

        

    }
```

I can't populate AspNetUserRoles with this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core Identity, IdentityUserRole is the entity used to represent the relationship between users and roles. You can create a class named UserRoleConfiguration to implement the <IdentityUserRole> interface to complete the binding of role to user. Here is an example that you can use as a reference.

```
public class AdminConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<WebApplication7User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<WebApplication7User> builder)
    {
        var admin = new WebApplication7User
        {
            Id = "2",
            UserName = "masteradmin",
            NormalizedUserName = "MASTERADMIN",

            Email = Admin@Admin.com,
            NormalizedEmail = ADMIN@ADMIN.COM,
            PhoneNumber = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            EmailConfirmed = true,
            PhoneNumberConfirmed = true,
            SecurityStamp = new Guid().ToString(),
            PasswordHash = "Password"
        };
        admin.PasswordHash = PassGenerate(admin);
        builder.HasData(admin);
    }
    public string PassGenerate(WebApplication7User user)
    {
        var passHash = new PasswordHasher<WebApplication7User>();
        return passHash.HashPassword(user, "password");
    }
}
public class RoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityRole>
{
     public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityRole> builder)
     {
         var role = new IdentityRole
         {
             Id = "2",
             Name = "Admin",
             ConcurrencyStamp = "b35494cf-4040-47e3-a6de-dee4b6f8e250",
             NormalizedName = "ADMIN",
         };
         builder.HasData(role);
     }
}

public class UserRoleConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IdentityUserRole<string>>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityUserRole<string>> builder)
    {
        builder.HasData(
            new IdentityUserRole<string>
            {
                RoleId = "2",
                UserId = "2"
                 
            }
        );
    }
}
```

My context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new RoleConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new AdminConfiguration());
    builder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserRoleConfiguration());

    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    
}
```

AspNetUsers：

[image]

AspNetRoles：

[image]

AspNetUserRoles：

[image]